# Can I filter the results from an OUTPUT clause without storing it in a table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on some SQL and using the OUTPUT clause for debugging. I've got a `DELETE FROM table OUTPUT DELETED.*` which displays my deleted records.

Is there any way to add a WHERE clause to that so I don't have to create a table specifically to store the OUTPUT in order to filter these results? It's got a few JOINs so there are 60+ columns I'd have to specify on any temporary table.

Comment: Are you trying to limit the number of COLUMNS...because DELETED.* is returning 60+ columns?  Is that the crux of your issue?

Comment: As for filtering output clause, the question was already asked and answered [here](/q/6660267/1178314), with comments toward more examples.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to define the columns (in a #temp or @variable or even real table) you want to track.

See my example here:

http://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2008/12/10/sqlserver20052008-output-clause-in-insertupdatedelete-statements/

sample of the code at the article:

```
delete from dbo.EmployeeTable
output deleted.EmpKey into dbo.AuditTable (EntityKey)
 where EmpAge > 0;
```